# Find the cardinality of this set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$P(A)$ represents the power set of $A$. The cardinality of $A$ is $m$.
$|\{X \in P(A) : |X| \leq 1\}|$?

I thought is was $2^m$ because $P(A)$ is a set containing $2^m$ elements. All of these elements are singular subsets. So now given 
that every element in $P(A)$ has cardinality less than or equal to $1$ it follows every element of $P(A)$ is in $|\{X \in P(A) : |X| \leq 1\}|$. So it too should have $2^m$ cardinality?

I looked in the back of my textbook and it said $m+1$. Really confused here.

Comment: The set builder notation indicates that you are looking at the number of 0 or 1 element subsets of $A$. There is exactly one 0 element subset, and each 1 element subset contains exactly one element of $A$, so there are $m$ of them. So, the answer is $m+1$.

Comment: Next time please format your mathematical expressions in MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference This time I formatted your question properly.

Comment: "All of these elements are singular subsets."  That is a *very* incorrect statement.  The elements can be any subset of any size.  Example if $A=\{a,b,c\}$ then $\{a,b\} \in P(A)$ and $\emptyset \in P(A)$ but $|\{a,b\}|=2\ne 1$ and $|\emptyset| = 0\ne 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing $X\subset A$ being a set (which can have as many elements as we like) with $X$ being a single item in $X \in P(A)$.  It would be absurd to say " All of these elements are singular subsets".

Example: Suppose $A = {1,2,3}$ and $m=|A| = 3$.  ANd so $|P(A)|= 2^3 = 8$.  ... okay, but *what* are the elements of $P(A)$.

Well, $P(A) = \color{green}{\big\{}\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\},\{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2, 3\}, A\color{green}{\big\}}$

Three of these elements are singular subsets:  $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}$.  But that's only three of them.  One of them is empty.  Three of them have order $2$. And one of them, $A$ itself, has three elements.

....

So does the answer make sense now.  It *can't* be $2^m$ because *not* all subsets are singletons.  But which subsets *are* singletons?

Well.... If $x\in A$ who many singleton sets contain $x$? Well,  a singleton set contains exactly one element so the only singleton set containing $x$ must be just $\{x\}$ and that's the only one.  Now there are $m$ elements in $A$ and for each element in $A$ there is exactly one singleton subset containing it.... so there are $m$ singleton subsets.

So $|\{X\in P(A):|X| = 1\}| = m$.  But we need the number of subsets that hame $1$ **or fewer** elements.  How many subsets have exactly $0$ elements?  Well, only $\emptyset$ has $0$ elements.

So $|\{X\in P(A):|X| \le 1\}| = m+1$

Example:  If $A= \{1,2,3\}$ then $\{X\in P(A): |X| \le 0\} = \color{orange}{\big\{}\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\color{orange}{\big\}}$

If you want to get specific:

$\{X\in P(A): |X| \le 1\} = $

$\{X \subset A: |X| =1\} \cup \{X\subset:|X|= 0\} =$

$\{\color{blue\{}x\color{blue\}}: x\in  X\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$.

So $|\{X\in P(A): |X| \le 1\}| =|\{\color{blue\{}x\color{blue\}}: x\in  X\}| + |\{\emptyset\}| =$

$|X| + 1 = m+1$.

Comment: Thank you all. I did exactly that! I counted the subsets of the power set rather than look for elements of the power set with cardinality less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This set that you have $A$ contains $m$ elements, so the powerset of $A$, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ does contain $2^m$ elements yes. However, the set that you are creating

$$
\{X\in\mathcal{P}(A) | |X|\leq 1\}
$$

is creating a new set! This new set is all subsets of your original set that have carnality of one or less. Obviously the individual element sets all are included

$$
\{\{a_1\},\{a_2\},...\{a_m\}\}
$$

and there are $m$ of these sets. However you need to remember that the empty set $\phi$ is also included in the powerset because it is a subset of every set. As such our new set that we created has those $m$ elements plus the empty set $\phi$ which is $m+1$ elements